# opensslErrorStack react error : when i try to start my project it show me this error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, nodes, node-modules

when I try to start my project it shows me this error:

```
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
```

actually, First, I removed the node_modules packages, so I thought if I removed it and then run `npm install` it will fix the error but nothing happen.

so I start to search on google,

1- `node --openssl-legacy-provider ./node_modules/.bin/gatsby build`

2-

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "export SET NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && react-scripts start",
    "build": "export SET NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

all this doesn't change anything.
any help please, I don't want to delete all the project and write it again.

Answer (score 0):

first, I had become angry, so I delete nodejs and npm from my system, after that I install it again luckily it works, but the issue isn't in nodejs, the error was in the package called

'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css'

It works when I remove it.